# Thread Injection on OSX

Tags: osx

Much reverse engineering has been done on Windows over the years leading to great undocumented functionality, such as using `NtCreateThreadEx` to [inject](http://securityxploded.com/ntcreatethreadex.php) threads across sessions.

On OSX the topic of thread injection seems relatively uncharted.  With the operating system being so incredibly large, where can I begin looking in order to uncover the functionality I desire?

For example, if someone were to ask me this about Windows, I would expect an answer telling me to begin reverse engineering `CreateRemoteThread` or to start looking at how the kernel creates user threads and point them into `ntoskrnl.exe`.

Comment: The [tag:software] is redundant as the majority of questions here involve software.

Comment: Seems that there are a significant number of hardware related questions as well.  If a hardware RE wanted to use this site, wouldn't it be nice if he/she could just put "software" on their ignored tags and be free from questions like mine?

Comment: A hardware RE could also add the [tag:hardware] to his favorite tags. It would have a similar effect. Do post you opinion here -> http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-should-software-questions-be-tagged

Comment: @AshRj Fair point. I'll fix it in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Admittedly, I don't know much about OSX, or even Linux.  But I would suggest looking at the [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/current/) source code.  GDB somehow is able to attach to running processes in order to debug them.  I would imagine this would, at least, provide similar functionality that you're looking for and prove a decent place to start.

If you're looking for a system call, it appears that `ptrace` is how GDB might do it.  Also, [here's](http://www.alexonlinux.com/how-debugger-works) a nice overview of how debuggers work.

**Update**:

Actually it seems that Uninformed wrote an [article](http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=4&a=3) that covers this topic somewhat.  In the article they discuss:

> A lot of people seem to move to Mac OS X from a Linux or BSD
>   background and therefore expect the ptrace() syscall to be useful.
>   However, unfortunately, this isn't the case on Mac OSX. For some
>   ungodly reason, Apple decided to leave ptrace() incomplete and unable
>   to do much more than take a feeble attempt at an anti-debug mechanism
>   or single step the process.

Also from that article, it looks like `thread_create_running` might be the function you're looking for.  [Link](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/thread_create_running.html) to the man page.

Comment: The Uninformed article is really great and I think right what I needed to get me started in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For OS X injection, I would look at the mach_star projects (mach_override and mach_inject)

https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star

Also, Pin now has os x support

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-binary-instrumentation-tool-downloads

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful -- I ended up writing a tutorial about this recently, since, as you note, documentation for this stuff is always so sketchy and often out of date.

http://soundly.me/osx-injection-override-tutorial-hello-world/